# Monodroid Multiple Timers

Tags: c#, timer, xamarin.android

Hey Guys this is my first question here on stackoverflow :)
So to get to my problem:
I have 3 different Timer classes which i want to call at different times:

```cs
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
     static public Timer Kundenerz = new Timer();
     static public Timer Kundenerz2 = new Timer();
     static public Timer Kundenerz3 = new Timer();

     protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
     {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        Kundenerz.Interval = 5000;
        Kundenerz.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler (Kundengroup);
        Kundenerz.Enabled = true;
        Kundenerz2.Interval = 5000;
        Kundenerz2.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler (Kundengroup2);
        Kundenerz3.Interval = 5000;
        Kundenerz3.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler (Kundengroup3);

    {

    public  void Kundengroup(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textView1 = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView1);

        Kundenerz.Enabled = false;
        textView1.Append ("HI");
        textView1.Append ("\r\n");
        Kundenerz2.Interval = 5000;
        Kundenerz2.Enabled = true;

    }

    public void Kundengroup2(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textView1 = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView1);
        Kundenerz2.Enabled = false;
        textView1.Append ("BYE");
        textView1.Append ("\r\n");
        Kundenerz3.enabled = true;  
    }

    public void Kundengroup3(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textView1 = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView1);
        Kundenerz3.Enabled = false;
        textView1.Append ("TRI");
        textView1.Append ("\r\n");
        Kundenerz.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

I want this part of my program to add "HI" to my TextView after the first 5s, then add "BYE" after another 5s while the other timer is stopped, then last but not least add "TRI" to it 5 seconds after "BYE" and then start the whole thing over again.
This doesn't work for me though, I only get a "HI" and then it stops doing anything.

I would appreciate any help, because this is the last thing i need to be done with my app :)

I'm pretty new to C# btw...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timers are fine, however they are running on their own thread, hence you need to use `RunOnUiThread` when wanting to update UI elements.

```
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    public static Timer Kundenerz = new Timer();
    public static Timer Kundenerz2 = new Timer();
    public static Timer Kundenerz3 = new Timer();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Kundenerz.Interval = 5000;
        Kundenerz.Elapsed += Kundengroup;
        Kundenerz.Enabled = true;
        Kundenerz2.Interval = 5000;
        Kundenerz2.Elapsed += Kundengroup2;
        Kundenerz3.Interval = 5000;
        Kundenerz3.Elapsed += Kundengroup3;
    }

    public void Kundengroup(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textView1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

        Kundenerz.Enabled = false;
        RunOnUiThread(() =>
                          {
                              textView1.Append("HI");
                              textView1.Append("\r\n");
                          });
        Kundenerz2.Interval = 5000;
        Kundenerz2.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void Kundengroup2(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textView1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        Kundenerz2.Enabled = false;
        RunOnUiThread(() =>
                          {
                              textView1.Append("BYE");
                              textView1.Append("\r\n");
                          });
        Kundenerz3.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void Kundengroup3(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textView1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        Kundenerz3.Enabled = false;
        RunOnUiThread(() =>
                          {
                              textView1.Append("TRI");
                              textView1.Append("\r\n");
                          });
        Kundenerz.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow thx alot :) That worked fine I tried to use RunOnUIThread before but it didnt work the way u wrote it worked! :)